# How to get Xcode root folder directory path using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file-manager

How to get the Xcode project root directory?

Example: `/Users/username/MyProjects/Project/`. similar to `${SRCROOT}`

I checked through `FileManager` `urls` and couldn't find the path.

**Goal**

I am running tests and would like to create a `log.txt` file in the project root directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no direct way to access this, but what you can do is this for simulator builds:

Modify your xcode scheme to add an environment var `SRCROOT` with the value `${SRCROOT}`

In your code, get the system environment using `ProcessInfo`:

```
let srcroot = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["SRCROOT"]
```

Comment: This will not let a simulator app to save a file on Mac

Comment: Did you try it? `let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: srcroot + "/dummy"); try "foo".data(using: .utf8)?.write(to: url)` just created a file on my machine.

Comment: I tried to interact with Mac file system via FileManager and it didn't work. I didn't try your way. Ok, thanks, it's good to know that it works